# How do I find out what pins of an Intel FPGA can be used to connect to different pin groups in EMIF?

Tags: pcb-design, intel-fpga, ddr, ddr3, ddr2

If I want to connect my Intel FPGA using EMIF to a high speed DDR Memory e.g Cyclone IV E to DDR3 memory or Max 10 to DDR2 memory, how do I find out what pins can be used for the data, strobe, clock, address and command signals?

As far as I know, we cannot just choose any pins on the FPGA. How do I know in advance? So far I have used development boards so the pins there were fixed. But how do I get answer this question when I am designing my own board and there is a level of flexibility in what I can choose?

There is also another layer of confusion created by the fact that some FPGAs have hard IP for EMIF and others do not. It is not clear if it is possible to use soft IP and a hard IP to support more than one EMIF on a single larger FPGA.

Comment: Read the documentation.

Comment: Which documentation?

Comment: The mountains of FPGA documentation that must exist for it. Yes, it's confusing. If it's anything like XIlinx it's spread over many many documents.